# unit test for socket wrap functions in lib or DLL without it's source code

Tags: unit-testing

i have a question about unit test. and i hope someone can give me some advice, thanks in advance.

here is my question. 
i need to write unit test for a lib base on google unit test (gtest), it's something about socket communication. and some of them wrapped low level socket functions, it means i need to do unit test for those functions as well. by the way, i have no access to the lib's source code =.=#

for example, say there is a function it called AcceptConnection(some arguments...), maybe it  wrapped SOCKET accept(SOCKET, SOCKADDR*， INT*). how can i test it. now without source code. it seems it's a question about how to write unit test for windows socket API.

i don't know if it's reasonable for me to write unit function for those wrapped functions and how can make the unit test more efficient.

regards

Joey Yu

[update]

i spent sometime tried to find if there are some way can solve it. it seems there wasn't now. without source code even have no idea what kind of system functions it use. the worst way use a parent process start the unit test application and redirect system call can't work.

Comment: What are you trying to test? your code or the socket functions?

Comment: @Sajit Kunnumkal: All functions in the lib.it was wrote by some guy in my team more than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this link http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies, which allows mocking for gtest.

You should probably mock all the low level socket functions and just test the code in the lib.

Comment: thanks you very much, i will pay some time on googlemock. but sadly, i have no source code for the lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install some hooks to the operating systems syscalls and check the calls that are being made...

Or You can try to automate some kind of checking in a strace output from the library.

[Here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/) is the first result for a "linux hooks" search, seems to be a nice way to hook calls on linux. And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) is a reference for kind of the same behavior on Windows. I haven't tried any of that BTW.